# Draw multiple python-igraph graphs from single jupyter/ipython cell

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, igraph

[Similarly to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16392921/1414809), I wanted to draw multiple graphs from a single ipython-notebook cell with the following code:

```
[1]:
%matplotlib inline
import igraph # it is `pip install python-igraph` on py2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

[2]:
# draws a graph successfully
igraph.plot(igraph.Graph.Erdos_Renyi(10, .5))

[3]:
for p in np.arange(.3, .8, .1):
    g = igraph.Graph.Erdos_Renyi(10, p)
    igraph.plot(g)
```

How can I show multiple graphs from `[3]` cell on a notebook?

It seems I could use this solution if I wanted to draw some matplotlib charts like this:

```
[4]:
for p in np.arange(.3, .8, .1):
    g = igraph.Graph.Erdos_Renyi(10, p)
    plt.loglog(sorted(g.degree(), reverse=True), marker='o')
    plt.show()
```

But this is not applicable to igraph graphs AFAICS. Is there some way to convert `igraph.drawing.Plot` to a more matplotlib familiar object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up to a solution like this:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, SVG

for p in np.arange(.3, .8, .1):
    g = igraph.Graph.Erdos_Renyi(10, p)
    print(p)
    display(SVG(igraph.plot(g)._repr_svg_()))
```

Same can be used for any object that supports `_repr_svg_()` or `_repr_png_()` so this is not python-igraph limited so far.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using igraph 0.8.2 and Python 3.7. The above answer didn't work for me:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'
```

I've found another way to do it using temporary file and reading an image from it:

```
import os
from IPython.display import display, Image

for p in np.arange(.3, .8, .1):
    g = ig.Graph.Erdos_Renyi(10, p)
    ig.plot(g).save('temporary.png') 
    display(Image(filename='temporary.png'))
    os.remove('temporary.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the first answer on newer Pythons you get :

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'
```

But you only need to modify the last line to read:

```
Display(SVG(igraph.plot(g)._repr_svg_()[0]))
```